Can't make menuconfig because terminal doesn't see ncurses
I am configuring android kernel as a root user and have installed ncurses libraries with
apt install libncursesw5-dev, but if I try to make menuconfig it doesn't see this
 *** Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the
 *** required header files.
 *** 'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.
 *** 
 *** Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again.
 *** 
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:198: scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:527: menuconfig] Error 2

If I try to install ncurses-devel or libnurses it cant find this package, typing libncurses or ncurses in terminal doesn't find any command
I tried installation from source, reinstalling and upgrading packages, updating apt, using apt-get, but nothing helped

The problem about installing ncurses on android doesn't look like a programming one, so it is off-topic on Stack Overflow: see [help/on-topic].
